# Different plot size on Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am currently using Basemap to plot some data. I would like the markersize to be defined by a list, but this throws an error.

Any idea how and I can show markers with varying sizes with a single function or method call?

```
m = Basemap(projection='mill',llcrnrlat=51.25,urcrnrlat=51.75,
            llcrnrlon=-0.5,urcrnrlon=0.3,resolution='h')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawrivers(color='blue')
m.fillcontinents()
m.drawmapboundary()
m.drawcounties()

lat,lon,size = [51.5, 51.4], [0.1, 0], [2, 35]
x, y = m(lon,lat)
m.plot(lon, lat,'ro',markersize=size)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`Basemap.plt` does not support multiple marker sizes. Use `Basemap.scatter` with its size argument instead.
If you want to keep both lines and markers, you have to combine `plot` with `scatter`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

m = Basemap(projection='mill',llcrnrlat=51.25,urcrnrlat=51.75,
        llcrnrlon=-0.5,urcrnrlon=0.3,resolution='h')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawrivers(color='blue')
m.fillcontinents()
m.drawmapboundary()
m.drawcounties()

lat,lon,size = [51.5,51.4],[0.1,0],[2,35]
x,y = m(lon,lat)
m.plot(x, y, c='r')
m.scatter(x, y, s=size, c='r', marker='o', zorder=2)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forwarding a list and not a values for the markersize. size=[2,35], try size[0]

Comment: That s the all point of it. I want the plot to have a different size. So how can I do this without forwarding a list ? I do have a very inelegant solution using a boucle, but I am pretty sure, we can find a pythonic way to do it.

Comment: The OP wants two different marker sizes. `plt.scatter` is the solution.